# IllegalStateException on setRequestedOrientation

Tags: java, android

i have a question about getting an `IllegalStateException` by calling `setRequestedOrientation`.

So in order that we have the portrait orientation globally I do it the following way:

```
registerActivityLifecycleCallbacks(new Application.ActivityLifecycleCallbacks() {
        @Override
        public void onActivityCreated(Activity activity, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

            // new activity created; force its orientation to portrait
            activity.setRequestedOrientation(
                    ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);

            //disable automatic screen lock
activity.getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON);

StatusBarUtil.setColor(activity, activity.getResources().getColor(R.color.black));
```

The error occurs on our lets say overlay activities. In order that they look like an overlay we're using the following theme for them:

```
<style name="Dialog" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Dialog">
        <item name="android:windowFrame">@null</item>
        <item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>
        <item name="android:background">@android:color/transparent</item>
        <item name="android:windowBackground">@android:color/transparent</item>
    </style>
```

I read on Stackoverflow that the error could occure when the following properties are set:

```
<item name="android:windowIsFloating">true</item>
<item name="android:windowIsTranslucent">true</item>
```

So I removed them and pushed a new update but unfortunately we got still the same error.

This is the throwing error trace reported by the in play console:

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: 
  at android.os.Parcel.readException (Parcel.java:1967)
  at android.os.Parcel.readException (Parcel.java:1905)
  at android.app.IActivityManager$Stub$Proxy.setRequestedOrientation (IActivityManager.java:6186)
  at android.app.Activity.setRequestedOrientation (Activity.java:5831)
```

I don't know if it's important but the base overlay activity itself is also calling the following code in the `onCreate` function:

```
getWindow().requestFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
```

Does someone has a similiar problem or can help here?

**Edit:**

It seems like the error only occurs on android phones which have android version 8 or higher. So as an example:

- Samsung Galaxy S7, 4096MB RAM, Android 8.0
- Samsung Galaxy S8, 4096MB RAM, Android 8.0
- LGE V30, 4096MB RAM, Android 8.0
- Samsung Galaxy A3(2017), 2048MB RAM, Android 8.0

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So the `IllegalStateException` is throwed by phones which are using android version 8 and up because Dialog activites inherit their orientation from parent and you can't set their orientation programmatically. Unfortunately the emulators running with android version 8 are not throwing this exception so I had to run it on a real device to figure this out. This is my kind of solution for this which works:

```
        try{
            // new activity created; force its orientation to portrait
            activity.setRequestedOrientation(
                    ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);
        }
        catch(Exception ignore){

        }
```